# jQuery Fancybox : how to make ajaxes cyclic / loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox, cycle

I use fancybox to show more info about items (description, sample image, big image, etc...) - to bring this to the fancybox the way I want I use fancybox's settings `'type': 'ajax'`,

and here comes the problem - the previous/next buttons=arrows are not available! ...even when I set `'cyclic': true` :(

Does anybody know how to turn on the cycling for ajax fancybox items?

Comment: check that all your links are sharing either the same `rel` OR `data-fancybox-group` attributes

Comment: @JFK thanks I always forget to group fancies xD! But - danger - data-fancybox-group is for fancybox 2.0+! I wrote it in one of my answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764068/fancybox-next-prev-not-working/18588920#18588920 :) Post your comment as an pretty answer and you will get accepted :) !

Comment: @jave.web : I assumed you were using v2.x (aren't you?) because you mention the word `loop` in the question's title, my bad.

Comment: No I am not :) Thing is I am actually using fancybox WP plugin (contains older fancybox) :) Loop was just another word for a cycle :)

Comment: JFK - dont you want make your comments into an answer ? :)